# Bijection from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (x, 2x+3) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

So, I need to construct some bijection from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (x, 2x+3) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

First I tried constructing $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (x, 2x+3) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, but I couldn't find a way to "remove" the line $y = 2x+3$ from range of $f$.
Then I tried constructing $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (x, 2x+3) : x \in \mathbb{R}\} \to \mathbb{R}^2$, but I couldn't get it to have the entire $\mathbb{R}^2$ as range. Explicitly, I tried $f(x,y) = (\frac{1}{2x+3-y}, y)$, but obviously $(0, x) \notin rng(f), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, where $rng$ is range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the idea of a bijection between $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$, just to push it down the line.  For the $1D$ case, you just send $0$ to $1, 1$ to $2, 2$ to $3$ and so on.  Here we can just send the line upward by one unit, then send that line upward, and so on.  So $$f(x,y)=\begin {cases} (x,y+1)&y=2x+2+k, k\in \Bbb N\\(x,y)&\text{otherwise} \end {cases}$$ where I have taken $0 \not \in \Bbb N$

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to move the line you have to $l=\{(0,y)\mid y\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Now, note that $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus l=\mathbb{R}^*\times\mathbb{R}$ and we are searching for a bijection from this set to $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ so it suffices to find one $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^*$. So let's define $f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x\quad\text{if } x\notin\mathbb{N}\\
x+1\quad\text{if }x\in\mathbb{N}
\end{cases}$
You could obviously compose the three steps to get an actual expression for the wanted bijection, but thought this way was more clear.